# Automatically rolling up cards in Angular 2 / Bootstrap

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

I just started working with Angular 2 and Bootstrap 4. I created about page using card class from Bootstrap. When you click on card its rolls down when you click again its rolls up. I will like to implement code so when I click on next one previous card automatically rolls up so I have always one card open.

Here is part of HTML file:

```
    <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" (click)="toggleShowSystemRequirements()">
              <h4>
                System Requirements
                <span class="pull-right" *ngIf="!showSystemRequirements"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></span>
                <span class="pull-right" *ngIf="showSystemRequirements"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></span>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="showSystemRequirements" class="card-block">
              <p>Software will operate on the following computers:</p>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  64-bit or 32-bit computer running Windows OS
                </li>
                <li>
                  64-bit or 32-bit computer running Linux OS
                </li>
                <li>
                  Mac OS X
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
<div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" (click)="toggleShowPSAT()">
         <h4>
              PSAT
           <span class="pull-right" *ngIf="!showPSAT"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></span>
           <span class="pull-right" *ngIf="showPSAT"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></span>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="showPSAT" class="card-block">
            <p>

            </p>

            <h4>Intended Users</h4>
            <p>

            </p>

            <h4>Inputs</h4>
            <p></p>
            <ul>
              <li>P</li>
              <li>System</li>
              <li>Number</li>
            </ul>

            <h4>Outputs</h4>
            <p>Base</p>
            <ul>

              <li>Optimization 
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
```

And here is my TS file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-about-page',
  templateUrl: './about-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./about-page.component.css']
})
export class AboutPageComponent implements OnInit {

  showSystemRequirements: boolean = false;
  showPSAT: boolean = false;
  showPHAST: boolean = false;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }


  toggleShowSystemRequirements() {
    this.showSystemRequirements = !this.showSystemRequirements;
  }
  toggleShowPSAT() {
    this.showPSAT = !this.showPSAT;
  }
  toggleShowPHAST() {
    this.showPHAST = !this.showPHAST;
  }
}
```

Comment: what is issue are you facing ?

Comment: @Jonnysai I'm will like when I click on new card previous one rolls up automatically. So far all cards stay open until I click on the card again.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve your requirement in several way one top my head

add new clearAll function it will simply reset your flags to false and call that function in your all cards click functions

```
    toggleShowSystemRequirements() {
    if(this.showSystemRequirements == false){
    this.clearAll()
    }

    this.showSystemRequirements = !this.showSystemRequirements;
  }


clearAll(flag){
this.showSystemRequirements  = false;
this.showPHAST = false;
this.showPSAT = false;
}
```